# Why doesn't my Gimp perspective transform apply to the entire image?

Tags: photo-editing, gimp, perspective

I'm trying to correct the perspective of a photo in GIMP, but I can't seem to get it to apply to the entire image. The transformation applies to a small area and leaves empty white space around it.

I start with this image:
[image: Image to be corrected]

When I select the Perspective tool and click anywhere in the canvas, the grid appears, already scaled to just the subject:
[image: Initial perspective grid]

I set up my transformation to line up the product label with the guides:
[image: Transformation to be applied]

And this is the result:
[image: Resulting image with ugly white space]

How can I get GIMP to transform the entire image, and not add that extra white space?

What I've tried so far:

- Extending the grid to cover the entire canvas - this results in stretching the subject
- Changing the Clipping setting - no effect
- Fit Canvas To Layers - no effect
- Removing the guides - no effect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say:

> When I select the Perspective tool and click anywhere in the canvas, the grid appears, *already scaled to just the subject*

Emphasis added, because that's important. *This is not the normal behavior of the perspective tool.* Normally, if you just click, the grid will cover the *entire* image. It sounds like you have your subject pre-selected. You don't describe having done that (and I don't see the "ants" in your screenshots), but perhaps you have "show selection" off (`ctrl-t`), and previously selected the subject area and forgot it.

The behavior when working with a selection of part of the image is exactly what you describe.

Comment: That was it! Actually it looks like "show selection" was on but for some reason it was still not showing; anyway, "select none" fixed it.

Comment: @Rena I wonder what appears if your selection lines up perfectly with your guides.

Comment: It doesn't in this case, or the perspective transform grid would up with the guide, too. An invisible selection frame gets reported occasionally, but we do not know why this happens: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678055. One guess is that the window state is somehow regarded as unexposed, i.e. as if it would be covered by another window.